# Assign action to NSMenuItem containing a submenu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenu

In Xcode i've created a simple menu item with a submenu (Submenu Menu Item from library). Its submenu has some specific actions but i also want the item itself to contain a click handler. Right now if i connect it to an action in a controller - it doesn't work. Is it even possible to do it?

Some piece of additional info: this menu item is a part of application's custom dock menu.

Google doesn't seem to be much of a help (or at least i can't find a "winner" keyword) so any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
NSMenuItem *mainItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];
[mainItem setTitle:@"Main item"];
NSMenu *submenu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
[submenu addItemWithTitle:@"Sub item" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
[mainItem setSubmenu:submenu];
```

Or,

```
NSMenu *newMenu;
NSMenuItem *newItem;

// Add the submenu
newItem = [[NSMenuItem allocWithZone:[NSMenu menuZone]] initWithTitle:@"Flashy" action:NULL keyEquivalent:@""];
newMenu = [[NSMenu allocWithZone:[NSMenu menuZone]]initWithTitle:@"Flashy"];
[newItem setSubmenu:newMenu];
[[NSApp mainMenu] addItem:newItem];
```

Comment: I think i didn't ask the question right. All of your (or mine for that matter) code works just fine, until ... we start dealing with the DOCK menu. Everything works in the App menu itself, but as soon as a menu item is added to the dock (right-click) menu - actions stop working on items that have subitems.